# Adding additional typescript types to third party modules for import in modules

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, types

I am new to typescript and hoping to get a better understanding of custom typings and extending types provided for third party modules.

For example, I am working on an express server using mongoose. Consider the following user model as an example:

```js
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
import { UserDocument, UserModel } from '../types';

const userSchema = new Schema<UserDocument, UserModel>(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    passport: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true;
  }
);

export default model('User', userModel)
```

In this model, the generic Document and Model types on the Schema are overridden by the `UserDocument` and `UserModel` that I have defined in the `types` directory.

```js
// ./types/user.d.ts

import {Document, Model} from 'mongoose';

export interface UserDocument extends Document {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
}

export interface UserModel extends Model<UserDocument> {}
```

This works fine when I explicitly import the type declarations.

However, when I tried to implement the UserDocument and UserModel types as part of a module declaration for mongoose I run into errors.

```js
declare module 'mongoose' {
  interface UserDocument extends Document {
    // ...from above
  }

  interface UserModel extends Model<UserDocument> {}
}
```

Then, in `user.model.ts`, rather than importing UserDocument and UserModel from `./types`, I do `import { model, Schema, UserDocument, UserSchema } from 'mongoose'`

Initially, this doesn't pose any IntelliSense issues in VSCode, however when I try to run/compile typescript throws errors that UserDocument and UserModel are not exported from module 'mongoose'.

Yet something like the two following snippets work for adding my environment variables to `process.env` and adding my additional properties to the `JwtPayload` from the jsonwebtoken package:

```js
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface ProcessEnv {
    NODE_ENV: string;
    PORT: string;
    DB_URI: string;
  }
}

declare module 'jsonwebtoken' {
  interface JwtPayload {
    role: string;
  }
}
```

Why does my second approach to providing typings for `UserDocument` and `UserModel` not work, yet the same approach appears to work for `process.env` and `JwtPayload`.